# What does 神逻辑 mean?

Tags: translation

I've encountered this word online. If you google "神逻辑" (with quotes) you'll find mostly instances where it's used as a standalone noun. Anyone know what it means, and maybe its origin/the explanation behind it?

Comment: evidently composed of 神 and 逻辑 ＂God logic＂，some say 神逻辑，就是神 ， which reminds people  of 神（上帝）是（一）个李群＂God is a Lie group＂

Comment: 神 here means "Extra-ordinary" or even "Super-natural"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a slang heavily used in online communities. I am not certain when it started. It means `perfect logic`, usually in a joking sense. Interestingly enough, it is also a sarcastic expression often used to accuse someone of his/her peculiar, erroneous logic.

A common instance of each would be:

**Sarcasm**

> Ａ：「我开会没有迟到，老板应该要给我加薪。」

"I was not late for the meeting. The boss shall give me a raise?"

> Ｂ：「这是什么神逻辑？」

"What kind of ('perfect') logic is that?"

**Compliment**

> Ａ：「如果老板不给我加薪，我钱会不够用；钱不够用，会买不起工具；买不起工具，就做不好工作；做不好工作，公司就会赔钱。所以老板一定会给我加薪。」

"If the boss does not give me a raise, I will not have enough money to use; without enough money to use, I cannot afford the tools; without the tools, I cannot do my job well; (if) I cannot do my job well, the company will make a loss. Therefore, the boss will certainly give me a raise."

> Ｂ：「我服了你的神逻辑。」

"I have nothing to comment on your perfect logic."